# How implement an HTTPS access to webapp deployed on Tomcat on EC2 AWS

Tags: ssl, tomcat, amazon-ec2, https

I'm new to AWS and the whole deployment stuff and I'm struggling since a week or so by reach the following goal by having the following scenario (also described in the attached diagram):
[image: Initial scenario and goal]

On the one side I have an aws ec2 instance with an Apache Tomcat installed on it. In the tomcat webapp directory I created one so called webapp but in reality there is just a website contains a little bit HTML, CSS and javascript. We call that webapp testabc. The public IPv4 DNS of the instance is for example ec2-1-23-45-678.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com. In the tomcat server.xml I changed the connector port to 80 so that my tomcat start page is accessible under http://ec2-1-23-45-678.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com and the webapp is accessible under http://ec2-1-23-45-678.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/testabc.

On the other side I have registered a domain we call as an example testabc.com and a subdomain app.testabc.com. Provider is IONOS. I also registered a wildcard certificate at IONOS for *.testabc.com. What I want to reach now is that the webapp testabc on the ec2 instance is securily accessible via https://app.testabc.com/testabc. First I registered a CNAME record in IONOS to the public IPv4 DNS so when I enter app.testabc.com/testabc a forwarding to the webapp on the ec2 instance is already possible. But I'm struggling now to implement HTTPS. What can you recommend me to do?

I've tried a few things so far but nothing of the following ways worked for me:

1. Starting from the assumption that it is necessary to first implement HTTPS access to the ec2 DNS before it is even possible to implement an HTTPS access via app.testabc.com (don't know if that is true?) I added security rules in my security group of the ec2 instance for port 443 and added 0.0.0.0\0 and ::\0 as sources. Furthermore I added a redirect to the server.xml in the tomcat conf directory: `<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443"/>`. But that alone does not work.
2. On the internet I found out that an ssl certificate is necessary to implement HTTPS access on tomcat webapp. So the assumption I made was that I have to get an ssl certificate for ec2-1-23-45-678.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com. So I followed the instructions of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ke1SgU_HY80&t=14s The result was that I could get access via https://ec2-1-23-45-678.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/testabc and even via https://app.testabc.com/testabc but in the browser there popped up a warning that the website is not secure. I found out that self-signed certificates provoke this error so that does not worked for me neither.
3. I found out that a ca certificate is the alternative that does not provoke this error. So I tried to create one via zerossl. With this type of certificate you have to validate that you are the owner of the DNS. I found out that you have to be the owner of the 'root' DNS, in my case it is amazonaws.com. Because I am not the owner of this domain of course this worked for me neither.
4. Next I found out that a load balancer in AWS could do the thing. So I followed the instructions of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA4X8ntcNBQ. In this tutorial you also have to generate an ssl certificate via ACM. Here the certificate is linked to the domain the user owns. In my case this would be the app.testabc.com what confuses me because there is already a wildcard certificate active through IONOS. Nevertheless I followed the instructions but then I don't know how to continue after creating the load balancer because it is said that you have to configure something in Apache server but I don't have an Apache but a Tomcat so I don't get what I should do then. So I asked another question on stack overflow to get it but this just lead me to things I already tried to do. For example making an SSL certificate via Cloudflare but that does not work because you cannot secure the domain ec2-1-23-45-678.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com here maybe because of the explanation in point 3.

So after doing all this with just the knowledge of a few youtube tutorials and stack overflow threads I am totally confused and also have the guess that I made wrong basic assumptions that lead me to the completely wrong path. To implement HTTPS sounds so basic to me because this is to me a requirement that every website and webapp has. And with my experiences I made the last days it feels like you build up so many components and bridges between them to just realize this basic requirement. I have now three running ssl certificates (one from IONOS, one from ACM and a self-signed one), two certificate generation trials with Cloudflare and zerossl which didn't worked, a load balancer and I am far away from getting HTTPS access to my webapp via my own subdomain without any warnings and errors. Hope you can help me with understanding what I've done wrong and lead me to the right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting started, trying to configure an AWS load balancer is probably going to be confusing and a lot of work for you. I would stick with just getting HTTPD to work on your EC2 instance, first. You can add other stuff, later.

First, almost everything you did so far was correct. Thanks for providing so much detail for your steps-so-far.

Second, your TLS certificate (which is required for HTTPS) is pretty important. If you indeed have a wildcard certificate from IONOS (or anybody, really), then that's the cert you should use. You will need the certificate itself and also the private key for it. You can also request a free certificate from AWS if you'd like. You will need to manually extract the key and certificate from AWS for use on your own EC2 server. (Note that the Common Name (CN) and Subject Alternative Name (SAN) fields for your TLS certificate should be *your domain name* and not the `compute.internal.amazon.com` thing.)

Third, you'll need to install those certificates into Tomcat. You need to do that by editing your `conf/server.xml` file and adding a new `<Connector>` like this:

```
<!-- HTTP Connector -->
<Connector port="443" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" ...[other attributes you might want]...>
  <SSLHostConfig ... />
</Connector>
```

You will need to look at the documentation for [SSLHostConfig](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_SSLHostConfig) to see how to configure it, and a lot depends upon the type of key you have (e.g. EC vs RSA, etc.), what format your key+cert are currently in (pkcs12 file, PEM files, etc.), and a few other things.

But this should be enough to get you started.